# Update specific properties in sonar-project.properties file from Maven pom.xml?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, sonarqube

I have a Spring Boot application that is making use of Maven as the build and dependency management tool. Maven version is 3.5.0.

SonarQube is being used to conduct static code analysis. Developers use the [SonarQube scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner) on their machine to scan the project prior to committing to Git. Jenkins is also running automated analysis using the Sonar Scanner for Jenkins. The SonarQube scanner expects a file named `sonar-project.properties` located at the root of the project. Both use cases mentioned above use the same `sonar-project.properties` file.

That being said, I would like to have some properties from in `sonar-project.properties` populated by Maven during the build, so we don't have to change them in two places all the time.

Some examples are:

- `sonar.projectVersion` (leveraging native version property in pom.xml)
- `sonar.java.source` (leveraging a property I have in pom.xml)
- `sonar.java.target` (leveraging a property I have in pom.xml)

Is it feasible? I am just starting to use Maven (coming from Ant) and I was able to do this in Ant quite easily.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally been able to meet the requirement using the `maven-antrun-plugin`.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>sonar-properties-replacement</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <propertyfile file="${basedir}/sonar-project.properties">
                        <entry key="sonar.projectName" value="${project.name}" />
                        <entry key="sonar.projectKey" value="${sonar.projectKey}" />
                        <entry key="sonar.projectVersion" value="${project.version}" />
                        <entry key="sonar.java.source" value="${java.version}" />
                        <entry key="sonar.java.target" value="${java.version}" />
                    </propertyfile>
                    <replaceregexp file="${basedir}/sonar-project.properties" match="^#.*\n" replace=""/>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
```

Tokens are in fact properties defined at the beginning of the pom.xml (java.version and sonar.projectKey), along with Maven native properties for project name and version.

That's not my preferred solution as I would have expected a native Maven for doing this common task, but that works very well.

If there is a native way to do this, please post your answer and I'll accept it right away.

Answer (score 3):

Yes Maven has feature of replacing placeholders with properties during build. It is called filtering. Depending on your use case you may need to add the following to your pom.xml

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
    <includes>
      <!-- To replace placeholders in sonar-project.properties -->
      <include>sonar-project.properties</include>
    </includes>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <!-- To process default resources located in src/main/resources folder of your project-->
    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>*.*</include>
    </includes>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

Maven has predefined property for project version with placeholder `${project.version}`
And for java versions you need to add custom properties to pom.xml like this

```
<properties>
   <java.source.version>1.7</java.source.version>
   <java.target.version>1.7</java.target.version>
</properties>
```

And after that your sonar-project.properties will contain these lines

```
sonar.projectVersion=${project.version}
sonar.java.source=${java.source.version}
sonar.java.target=${java.target.version}
```

Comment: Is it supposed to replace the value of ${project.version} with the one from pom.xml (1.0.0.RELEASE for example)? I am using the generic Sonar Scanner, which is not tightly coupled to Maven. What I would like is a way to set the values for specific properties in sonar-project.properties rather than just having a symbolic link between sonar-project.properties and pom.xml. Feasible?

Comment: Yes, it will take value from pom.xml for all properties including version (1.0.0.RELEASE). I though that you are running Sonar Scanner as a part of Maven build

Comment: I was, but I have changed my mind and decided to go for the generic Sonar Scanner. On my side when I do `mvn clean compile`, values aren't getting updated as expected. For example, I see: `sonar.projectName=${project.name}`, `sonar.projectVersion=${project.version}`, `sonar.java.source=${java.version}` and `sonar.java.target=${java.version}`. Am I missing something? Maybe some executions?

Comment: File with replacements is located in folder with compiled classes like target/classes. Maven doesn't make replacements in the source file itself.

Comment: Okay, so that doesn't meet the requirement. In Ant, I was able to load any properties file in memory during the course of a build target (through `<propertyfile file="${basedir}/sonar-project.properties">`), and then change the value of a specific property (Ant calls it a key) like so: `<entry key="sonar.projectName" value="${app.name}" />`. Maven being so powerful, there must be a way of manipulating file like Ant does??

Comment: Maven has a lot of plugins. But the idea is that you are using Maven for everything: first step compiles java code and replaces placeholders, second step executes unit tests, third step starts sonar-scanner (or uses Maven plugin for Sonar), forth step packages code into jar/war/zip, and fifth step deploys artifact to binary repository.